# Comparing date fields of two tables in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to define a rake task where I want to compare the data fields of two tables. Issues table **has_many relationship** with messages table(message table has **issue_id**). The table has a date field as a DateTime data type

Issues table is having has_many relationship with billings table also(billings table has **issue_id**). This table also has a date field as a DateTime data type.

So what I am trying to achieve in the logic is that I want to compare that **issue.billings.last.date < issue.messages.last.date**. But I am not sure how to achieve that.

```
Business.all.each do |business|
  business.issues.where("issues.amount > 0"). each do |issue|
    {logic}
  end 
end
```

Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to fetch all issues which have `issue.billings.last.date < issue.messages.last.date` ?

Comment: Yes i want all of them which verify this condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.....

```
Business.all.each do |business|
  business_issues = business.issues.includes(:billings, :messages).where("issues.amount > 0").select { |issue| (issue.billings.last.date < issue.messages.last.date) if issue.billings.present? && issue.messages.present? }     
end
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `date' for nil:NilClass
I tried this and above is the error which I am getting.

Comment: It seems like you don't have billings and messages for some issues. I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Akshay just a question what if there was no relation between the issues and messages table and I had to compare the issues.billings.last.date to the messages.last.date.

Comment: How can I access the ID of the issues and last billings ID from the result?